# Непрерывная передача видео по сети

Tags: трансляция, http, видео, c++, streaming

Всем доброго времени суток!

Задача такая. Есть моя программа на C++, которая ретранслирует видео клиентам, подключенным к ней (плеерам, телевизорам и т.д.). Видео она может брать из любого источника, но для простоты будем говорить, что видео получается путем такого же подключения к какому-то другому серверу в интернете. Ретрансляция работает, но если поток видео по каким-то причинам временно недоступен (может скорости не хватает, может сервер вырубился и т.д.), то все клиенты, по истечению какого-то времени отключаются. А мне бы хотелось сделать такую возможность, что когда видео недоступно, то все клиенты получали бы какую-то картинку, обозначающую эту проблему (например, картинку "Идет загрузка"). В этом случае все плееры бы думали, что трансляция идет как и прежде, и сам человек решал бы нужно ли ему от нее отключаться или нет.

Вот у меня есть такой простенький код:

```
void LoadMovieThread::sendLoadMovie(){
    char buff[4096];
    if(!this->loadMovieFile){
        this->loadMovieFile = fopen("movie\\LoadingMovie.ts", "rb");
    }
    if(this->loadMovieFile){
        int bytes_read = fread(&buff[0], 1, 4096, this->loadMovieFile);
        if(MForm->SrvThread && MForm->SrvThread->serverActive == true){
            MForm->SrvThread->SendToAll(&buff[0], bytes_read);
        }
        if(bytes_read < 4096 && feof(this->loadMovieFile)){
            rewind(this->loadMovieFile);
        }else if (ferror (this->loadMovieFile)){
            fclose(this->loadMovieFile);
            this->loadMovieFile = NULL;
        }
    }

}

void __fastcall LoadMovieThread::Execute() {
    while(!Terminated){
        if(this->active){
                this->sendLoadMovie();
        }
        Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Функция SrvThread->SendToAll занимается тем, что отправляет контент всем подключенным клиентам. В данный момент видео передается по http (протокол, скорее всего, называется http live streaming, хотя судя по его описанию должен передаваться еще и плэйлист, который и прогрывается по порядку всеми клиентами).

Но проблема состоит в том, что, когда я хочу возобновить передачу основного потока видео и остановить мой "загрузочный" ролик, плеер иногда (даже можно сказать, чаще всего) сам собой отключается от моего сервера. Плеер - VLC. В логах вижу примерно следующее:

```
libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 13, expected 12) for PID 0
```

Т.е. в потоке наблюдается какой-то разрыв, который и не понимает плеер. В инете про это кое-что есть, но конкретной инструкции по устранению данной беды я не нашел.

Может кто знает, как лучше будет сделать такое? Не обязательно использовать http. Может такую возможность предусматривает rtsp или какой-то другой протокол. Все что мне надо - это как-то сообщить плееру, что, мол, "сейчас к тебе должен прийти совсем другой ролик и не нервничай по этому поводу". В принципе, я думаю такая возможность где-то должна быть предусмотрена. Вдруг какой-то интернет-тв провайдер захочет вставить свою рекламку и т.д. Мой то ролик это, по сути, то же самое, что и такая реклама....

Да, и еще... Видео у меня закодировано в том же формате и с тем же кодеком, что и входной поток. Могу даже выложить инфу с MediaInfo, если будет нужно...

Пожалуйста, подскажите, в какую сторону мне копать. Заранее спасибо.